# Swap user in e-mail trigger for list of users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a trigger so that when a new user is logged, I get an e-mail:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create trigger [dbo].[NewUser] on [dbo].[UserTable]
for insert
as
    declare @UserName [nvarchar](max);
    select @UserName = i.UserName from inserted i;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'SQLSERVERNAME',
        @recipients = 'my-email@my-company.com',
        @subject = 'New user identified',
        @body = @Username

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserTable] ENABLE TRIGGER [NewUser]
GO
```

This worked fine for my original purpose, i.e. a new user visits the site and it'll take their Windows credentials and create a new profile all on a one by one basis.

But in a staging environment, I just inserted a few new users in one go:

```
insert into MyDatabase.[dbo].[UserTable]
    ([UserName]) values ('User1'), ('User2'), ('User3') --etc.
```

I got only one e-mail, for the first user, and an error message in SSMS saying mail was queued.

I sent a test e-mail and that came through ok.

I tried `Select * from msdb.[dbo].[sysmail_unsentitems]` and there's nothing in there.

I think the case is that actually, I should've only receive one e-mail but with a list of new users, but I'm not sure how do I change the trigger to create a list of new users and then iterate over to write each of them to the body?

Please bear in mind this is SQL SERVER 2008!

Comment: Use `SELECT .. FOR XML PATH` to concatenate user names from `inserted`

Comment: Bear in mind that SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported - someone at your organization should be very concerned about that.

Comment: Yeah, it's me that's concerned, I just joined and they had no idea until I told them EOL was January, It's just acting as a staging environment for the short term before we smash it up with a big hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is broken.  You are assuming that only one row is inserted.

You need to loop through the `insert` table (well, it is really a view) to send a separate email for each user.  Or, you can concatenate the values together if you only want one value.  It is not clear which you prefer.

That said, I would also discourage you from sending an email on a trigger.  It is quite an expensive operation and it looks resources in the database.  A better method is to use [message queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15).  The idea is that you post a "message" in a queue and *another process* reads the message and sends the email.  The resources in the database are then not locked for the actually sending of the email.